# Editing a list of users accounts to have the same expiration date

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I've been tasked with setting all users in our AD that are contractors to have their accounts expire at the end of our phiscal year. This sounds like a relatively easy task, but it's been giving me issues.

All of our contractor accounts start with "c_" making them easy to find with

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties SAMAccountName | Where {$_.SAMAccountName -like "c_*"} | Select SAMAccountName | Export-Csv -LiteralPath C:\Results\AllContractors.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Then it should just be a matter of adapting the command

```
Set-ADAccountExpiration -Identity "SAMAccountName" -DateTime "07/01/2023"
```

to be repeated for every SAMAccountName I have in the .csv.

All together I get this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties SAMAccountName | Where {$_.SAMAccountName -like "c_*"} | Select SAMAccountName | Export-Csv -LiteralPath C:\Results\AllContractors.csv -NoTypeInformation

$Users = Import-Csv -LiteralPath C:\Results\AllContractors.csv

ForEach($User in $Users){
    Set-ADAccountExpiration -Identity $User -DateTime "07/01/2023"
    }
```

But it keeps returning an error:

```
Set-ADAccountExpiration : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:4 char:5
+     Set-ADAccountExpiration -Identity $User -DateTime "07/01/2023"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Microsoft.Activ...ement.ADAccount:ADAccount) [Set-ADAccountExpiration], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADAccountExpiration
```

Any insight into this would be appreciated!

Comment: `$User.SamAccountName` most likely :)

Comment: It's a crime that they let me anywhere near a computer. Thank you! This was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue most likely is because you're passing a `PSCustomObject` (`$user`) with a property named `SamAccountName` and `Set-ADAccountExpiration` does not know how to interpret it as its expecting the property value (`$user.SamAccountName`). Also you can definitely do all of this in a single pipeline using `-PassThru`. No need to export and then import back the CSV:

```bash
Get-ADUser -Filter "samAccountName -like 'c_*'" |
    Set-ADAccountExpiration -DateTime '07/01/2023' -PassThru |
    Select-Object SamAccountName |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath C:\Results\AllContractors.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I like this! Thanks for the tip! and this completely avoids the issue I was having in the first place so thats great!